# Decimal to Hex to Decimal

Tags: sas

im reading in some data where numbers that were originally hex have been read in as decimal.

As these hex examples are all also valid decimal numbers, when I have read them in from a text file SAS has read then as decimal.

Examples are 53 and 68, which are the hex numbers for 83 and 104 decimals respectively.

Using the hex2. format converts 53 and 68 into hex numbers (68 becomes 44 for example), which is not what I want.

Is there away to get SAS to recognise 53 and 68 as hex without trying to convert them to hex?

Answer (score 4):

Use the informat `hexw.`. Recall that informats and formats are different.

**Informat**

> An informat is a type of SAS language element that applies a pattern to or executes instructions for a data value to be read as **input**.

**Format**

> A format is a type of SAS language element that applies a pattern to
>   or executes instructions for a data value to be displayed or written
>   as **output**.

A good way to remember it:

A **format** is how *you* see it

An **informat** is how *SAS* **in**ternally sees it

**Explanation**

**In**formats are used to convert **in**put values to something that SAS can appropriately perform mathematical operations on. For example,

`01JAN2015`

By itself, it's just a character string. SAS doesn't know how to perform math on `01JAN2015`, and it will read the value in as a character string automatically. But, SAS *does* know how to interpret what that string represents. You just need to tell SAS to interpret it in a certain way.

For SAS to do math on dates, it uses a reference date of 1/1/1960. By applying the informat `date9.`, SAS is able to understand that the string represents the 20,089th day since 1/1/1960. The output will then look as such:

`20089`

That's hard for people to read. You can apply the `mmddyy10.`  format to this so that you can read it, but SAS can also understand it. Format will not change what SAS sees. The value is still stored as a decimal, but the way it's displayed to you is more readable.

```
**To SAS**         **To you**
date               date
20089              01/01/2015
```

In your case, SAS knows the value you're reading is numeric. It will automatically assume it's a decimal, but we know for a fact that it is not.

Following the above logic, we want to apply an informat to the numeric values so SAS will interpret the values as hex, and not decimals.

```
data want;
    informat hex_value hex2.;
    input hex_value;
datalines;
53
68
;
run;
```

Your table will look as such:

```
hex_value
83
104
```

If you apply the format `hex2.`, you'll see the output table as hex again. Since we've already interpreted the value, we're just changing how it looks to you, but not how it looks to SAS:

```
**To SAS**         **To you**
hex_value          hex_value
83                 53
104                68
```